# Substring string with regex before first match in Java

Tags: java, regex

Is it possible to substring string with regex before first match in Java?

```
String str = "&&param1=value 1&&param1=value&2&&param1=value & 2&param2=aaas&param3=99&param4=bbb";
```

I want to have a result like this:

```
&&param1=value 1&&param1=value&2&&param1=value & 2
```

Comment: I mean that in string when meet first (&anything=) ,  as substring end position take that position

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this regex for matching your test:

```
^.*?(?=(?<!&)&\w+=)
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/qE1uG7/1)

In Java this regex will be:

```
"^.*?(?=(?<!&)&\\w+=)"
```

Answer (score 0):

If you simply want to split the string with spaces, you can try the following code

```
String str = "&&param1=value 1&&param1=value&2&&param1=value & 2&param2=aaas&param3=99&param4=bbb";
String[] strAray = str.split(" ");//strArray contains all the splitted tokens
for(String s : strAray){
    System.out.println(s);//Prints out each token
}
```